# Rails is killing special charcters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, utf-8, assets

Something inside rails is preventing the the files to be served in utf-8.

Did they add some new config for utf-8? I'm running rvm ruby 2 and rails 4

[image: Wrong encoding]

Comment: Okay it looks like it has nothing to do with Rails

http://superuser.com/questions/670808/files-saved-in-utf-8-shown-broken-in-browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a missing header or something that would be telling your browser that the text is in UTF-8. Your HTML page should contain something like

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

or

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

assuming it is HTML.

Comment: but i never needed that before. textmate saves it in utf-8 how else can i set the header?

Comment: you are talking about html, this is not an html file, I've opened a js file in a browser on the left

Answer (score 0):

I used to put that on the first line:

```
#encoding: utf-8
```

Comment: thats invalid javascript and i also can't do that because the javascript file is in a gem

Comment: I thought was a html too.